# Vim terminal: How to split below by default?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

Opening the vim terminal using `:term`, creates a horizontal split with the terminal placed at the top half of the window. Is there a way to open the terminal at the bottom half instead?

I know I can use `set splitbelow` to make all horizontal splits open below the current one. However, I only want the `set splitbelow` behaviour to apply when opening `:term`. I want all other horizontal splits to open above as usual.

Comment: Apparently "splitbelow" is default set Maybe split refers to the current page, `split` splits the screen, `splitbelow` splits the current screen putting it below, `nosplitbelow` means it's not okay to split the current screen putting it below If the split family refers to the current screen, this is the logic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`:belowright`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abelowright):

```
:belowright terminal
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
:bel term
```

This command is a modifier and affects the command run right after it.

(Another useful modifier here is [`:vertical`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Avertical), to split vertically instead.)

Comment: [@filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden) Thank you for the answer but how to modify the behavior permanently. What entry will go in .vimrc file ?

Comment: @ankitj You have `set splitbelow` that you can add to your vimrc, but that will affect any splits, not just the `:terminal`.

Comment: @ankitj You can add `cnoremap term bel term` to your .vimrc to permanently remap `:term`  to `:bel term`. If you do that and find yourself wanting to type just `term` in the command line, you can pause for a moment after typing the `t` or the `e` to get Vim to stop looking at it as a potential start to the remap.